# Using jQuery with HTML5 progress bar

Tags: jquery, html

I want to use jQuery to update the value of my progress bar that I am using.

```
<progress id="progBar" value="10" max="100">
```

I want to update this everytime someone push a button to change the value up by one but I don't know the code.

I have tried using `val(15) .progressbar({ value: 15 })` but it won't update to 15.

Can someone give me a solution?

Comment: How about `.progressbar('value', 15);` ?

Comment: I tried, but it doesn't work either. :/

Answer (score 13):

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/fJxGG/1/

Both seem to work on Chrome & FF -

```
$('#progBar').attr('value',50);
$('#progBar').val(70);
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
$('#click').click(function() {
  // Get progress bar current value and add with 1;
  var curr_val = $('#progBar').val();
  var new_val = Number(curr_val) + 1;
  $('#progBar').val(new_val);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" id="click">Click me</button>
<progress id="progBar" value="10" max="100">
```

Comment: Please explain your solution. Do not enter code only

Answer (score 1):

have you tried `$("#progBar").attr("value", 15);` ?

Comment: Yes, it works. I had a flaw in the back end keeping it the same value.

Comment: Please note that since jQuery 1.8 this method is deprecated: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/blob/master/warnings.md#jqmigrate-jqueryattrfn-is-deprecated. Use `$('#progBar').val(70);` instead.